# Is it correct to use "they" for an abstract object?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is correct:

> The rules were challenged because **they impose** an onerous burden.
>
> The rules were challenged because **it imposes** an onerous burden.

The second one seems to be wrong because it uses the singular "it" to describe the plural object "the rules", but how should the sentence be fixed? By using the first sentence?

Comment: Be consistent with the tense. The rules were challenged because they imposed ..., or the rules are being challenged because they impose ...

Comment: Whyever not? _Rules_ is plural, so it takes a plural pronoun.

Comment: In English, *they* is third-person plural (and often singular also) regardless of gender (male/female/neuter/etc).

Comment: 'The times, they are a-changin'.'